# Как при нажатии на кнопку скопировать текст из input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, copy

Нужно при нажатии на кнопку скопировать текст из input, только как это сделать я не очень понимаю)

html:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="table-tr">
        <td id="table-text" class="table-td" width="80%"><input type="text" value="Как тебя зовут?: Ирина"></td>
        <td onclick="copytext('#table-text')" class="table-td table-td__copy"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function copytext(el) {
    var $tmp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($tmp);
    $tmp.val($(el).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $tmp.remove();
} 
});
```

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед? Ведь есть уже готовая библиотека `clipboard.js`. Или вам принципиально это нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адаптированный код под вашу ситуацию.

```js
function copytext(el) {
    $(el).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <tr class="table-tr">
        <td id="table-text" class="table-td" width="80%"><input type="text" value="Как тебя зовут?: Ирина"></td>
        <td onclick="copytext('#table-text input')" class="table-td table-td__copy">Скопировать</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: мне кажется, нажимать на `td` для копирования даже в его ситуации - это абсурд

Comment: Полностью согласен.